# Accounting for minimum dependent measure in data when fitting a distribution

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, extreme-value

I have what is possible a naive question. I am current comparing various models (i.e. distributions). And the comparisons do not involve different distributions but rather how the model is fed the data.

For example, two models might be 1) a mixture of a gamma + exponential and 2) a mixture of a gamma + exponential wherein the minimum data point is subtracted. With respect to model 2). If I subtract the minimum data then I am left with a data point = 0. The model's fit fine and I get my MLE values.

However, If I am working with just a gamma and in one model I remove the minimum data point, then that data point = 0 causes errors in the MLE estimator. To get past this issue I simply remove the 0 data point and fit the distribution.

My question is, is there a problem with simply removing the data point (my worry is decreasing the size of my data set)? And should I do that for the gamma + exponential as well?

Thanks

Comment: In the case where the data is shifted exponential, subtracting the smallest data point (and removing the 0) leaves you with exponential. More generally, once you've subtracted, the zero itself won't contain any information - it's a consequence of your transformation and tells you nothing about the distribution. Whether subtracting the smallest is in general a good idea may be another matter, but if you're doing it, I'd suggest throwing out the 0 as a matter of course. It's the subtraction that decreased the effective size of the data set, not tossing the value that shows it.

Comment: The minimum is thought to represent the minimum time necessary for the process of interest to complete. And in fact, when we subtract the minimum the Loglikelihood value is much larger than if the minimum remained in the set.

However, in discussing this issue with my advisor, removing zeros is problematic not because it reduces sample size but because it biases the sample (because the zeros are systematic and not randomly generated in the data set). 

To get pass this issue, we subtract all but 0.005 of the minimum. It's a bit arbitrary but does the job and the distributions fit very well.

Comment: If the data were exponential, *keeping* the zeros is a source of bias in estimation of the exponential mean, while tossing them out doesn't lead to bias.